# Proper way to run a backend project in a VPS

Tags: django, pycharm, windows-server-2008, vps

I have a project in `Pycharm` which is `django`. its backend is `mySQL` and uses `redis-server` and `memcached`. my `VPS` is `Windows-server 2008`.

- In order to run it in a `VPS` do i have to move the whole IDE with the project, to `VPS` and just hit **Run** in the IDE?

It's my first time running a server of my own and it's the only way i can think of. please do correct me if i missed the whole concept.

Comment: No. Please read the very comprehensive [documentation on deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for directing me in the right path, i think i found my way now :)